# ToC chapter number width & memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, chapters, width

I've changed the chapter numbering to Roman, and now I want to increase the number width in the table of contents in order to avoid overlapping with chapter titles.

The usual trick

```
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}
```

with `tocloft` package doesn't work here because of the conflict with the class `memoir`. And when I try

```
\DisemulatePackage{tocloft}
```

a lot of errors appear.

How can I do ?

Here's a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand \thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Chapter one}
\chapter{Chapter two}
\chapter{Chapter three}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the length `\cftchapternumwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{5em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Chapter one}
\chapter{Chapter two}
\chapter{Chapter three}

\end{document}
```